# проблема в адаптации navbar bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, frontend, slim

[image: на малому девайсі]
[image: на більшому]

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-style
  .container
        .navbar-header
          button.navbar-toggle data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-header-colapse"
            .sr-only Відкрить навігацію
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
          = link_to 'KanivHelp', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand'
        .collapse.navbar-collapse.nav-header-colapse
          ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
            li = link_to 'Вхід', new_session_path unless current_user
            li = link_to 'Реєстрація', new_user_path unless current_user
            li = link_to 'Вихід', session_path, method: :delete if current_user
            li = link_to 'Створити Пост', new_post_path if current_user
            li.navbar-text-login = current_user.first_name if current_user
```

после нажатия кнопки ссылки не выдвигаются

Comment: А откуда вы брали пример?

Comment: Забыл подключить JS от Bootsrtap, уже все исправил